# send height from javascript function to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm calculating the height of an iframe using a JavaScript function and store it in a Variable, now I want to send that variable to jQuery to set the height().

My JavaScript function

```
function iframeLoaded()
{
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById('ftwo');
    iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}
```

The functions works fine because when I alert the value, it display it correctly, and I'm in the same domain that I'm calculating the height

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ftwodiv").height(iFrameID);
});
```

on my body tag I have this:

```
<iframe id="ftwo" width="455px" onLoad="iframeLoaded()"  
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.company.com"></iframe>
```

I tried some stuff that did not work.

Comment: return the height form the function...`return iFrameID.height`...

Comment: FYI:  jQuery is a toolbox written in pure JavaScript.  And since you have jQuery, you do not need to use any inline code, `onLoad="iframeLoaded()"`.

Comment: Is the URL being loaded in the `iframe` local i.e. on the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can return that from the function and use it.,.

```
function iframeLoaded(){
     var hgt = 0;
     var iFrameID = document.getElementById('ftwo');
     hgt = iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

     return hgt;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var iFrameID = iframeLoaded();
    $("#ftwodiv").height(iFrameID);
});
```

You can also use a Global variable to achieve the same..

```
var iFrameHeight = 0;

function iframeLoaded(){
         var hgt = 0;
         var iFrameID = document.getElementById('ftwo');
         iFrameHeight  = iFrameID.height = FrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ftwodiv").height(iFrameHeight);
    });
```

But the first approach is cleaner